# Not able to fetch Assosiate objects from database

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an object of XYZ that takes a Set of Objects of KZP class. I need to persist XYZ and all the KZP objects in database. In first go, I am only able to persist XYZ not KZP in first go. But when I update XYZ again then all the KZP objects that I give get saved.

```
hbm.xml file for XYZ...

    <property name="statusLevel" column="status_level" type="string"/>
            <property name="isDeleted" column="is_deleted" type="boolean" not-null="false"/>
            <set name="rules" inverse="true" cascade="all">
                <key column="card_id"></key>
                <one-to-many class="com.KZP" />
            </set>


HBM.xml file for KZP
<many-to-one name="ffpCardData" class="com.XYZ" column="card_id" fetch="join" lazy="false" cascade="all"/>
    </class>
```

Now by using this I am able to save the main object with set of KZP object but not able to fetch it. Would you please tell me what needs to be changed in configuration.

Comment: We definitely need to know how the entities are defined and how you persist the XYZ entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your m.xml file for XYZ:

```
<set name="rules" lazy="false" fetch="join" inverse="true" cascade="all">
  <key column="card_id"></key>
  <one-to-many class="com.KZP" />
</set>
```